# Rails validation prevent email addresses and phone numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I am looking for a way in Rails (2.3.9) to PREVENT users from entering email addresses, and phone numbers of as many formats as possible. I have a textbox, and I do not want users to be able to submit email addresses or phone numbers..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward method would be to use a custom validation with [validate](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validate). You can check against the regexes you want to prevent users from submitting and supply your own validation message.

I've created [a gist demonstrating this behavior](https://gist.github.com/1193878).